# ¿Cómo puedo ordenar correctamente un H2 y un Párrafo?

Tags: html, css

estoy recién aprendiendo HTML & CSS, eh intentado buscar solución a esto.

Cómo tengo mi proyecto hasta el momento

*Así es cómo está mi página*

> [image: Así es cómo está mi página]

*Cómo se ve el ejemplo los H2 y H3 deben quedar al costado derecho*

> [image: Cómo se ve el ejemplo los H2 y H3 deben quedar al costado derecho]

Cómo se ve en la primera imagen tengo los Párrafos ordenados de manera normal, pero necesito que queden cómo se ve en la fotografía .

Además de darle un tamaño a ese HR, para lograr que sea más pequeño.
Muchas gracias por su atención :)

Mi codigo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Imagenes/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Estilo.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Mis Perris</title>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Cabezera -->
    <header>
        <img src="Imagenes/logo.png" alt="LogoPerrito" class="Logo">
        <ul class="Listado">
            <li><a href="#!">Inicio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">Quienes Somos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">Servicios</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">Contacto</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header> 

    <!-- Eslogan & Más -->
    <div class="Landing">

        <img src="Imagenes/perro.png" alt="Perro" class="Perrito1">
        <h2 class="Eslogan">+569 98765431</h2>
        <h2 class="Eslogan_Center">Rescate y adopción de perros callejeros</h2>
        <ul class="Redes_Sociales">
            <li><img src="Imagenes/social-inst.png" alt="Insta"></li>
            <li><img src="Imagenes/social-twitter.png" alt="Twitter"></li>
            <li><img src="Imagenes/socialfacebook.png" alt="Facebook"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- Cuerpo de la página -->
    <section class="Container">
        <section class="Container">
            <div class="Contenido_Derecha">
                <h1 class="Conte_1">RESCATE</h1>
                <h3 class="Conte_1">ETAPA UNO</h3>
                <hr class="Conte">
                <br>
                <p class="Parrafo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam ultricies hendrerit quam, eget finibus metus gravida vitae.</p>
                <img src="Imagenes/rescate.jpg" alt="Perrito2" class="Perrito2">
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="Container">
            <div class="Contenido_Izquierda">
                <img src="Imagenes/crowfunding.jpg" alt="Alimento" class="Alimento">
                <div>
                <h1>CROWFUNDING</h1>
                <h3>FINANCIAMIENTO</h3>            
                <hr class="Conte">
                <br>
                <p class="Parrafo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam ultricies hendrerit quam, eget finibus metus gravida vitae.</p>
                <br>
                <input type="button" value="Boton" class="Boton">
            </div>
        </section>   
    </section> 

    <!-- Pie de Página  -->
    <footer class="Foter">
        <h3 class="Ultimos">Desarrollo Web & Mobil</h3>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Podrás compartir el código hecho hasta ahora?

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, es preferible en la medida de lo posible que deje un log de texto y no una imagen del mismo, pues hace mas fácil su lectura para los usuarios, puede ver compartir, editar, cerrar, reportar, pudiendo acceder a editar presionado sobre el, y cambiando la imagen por el log de texto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mira a ver si este ejemplo te puede ayudar

```css
body{
text-align:right;

}
hr{
width:60px;
float:right;
}
```

```html
<!-- Cabezera -->
<header>
    <img src="Imagenes/logo.png" alt="LogoPerrito" class="Logo">
    <ul class="Listado">
        <li><a href="#!">Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">Quienes Somos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">Servicios</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">Contacto</a></li>
    </ul>
</header> 

<!-- Eslogan & Más -->
<div class="Landing">

    <img src="Imagenes/perro.png" alt="Perro" class="Perrito1">
    <h2 class="Eslogan">+569 98765431</h2>
    <h2 class="Eslogan_Center">Rescate y adopción de perros callejeros</h2>
    <ul class="Redes_Sociales">
        <li><img src="Imagenes/social-inst.png" alt="Insta"></li>
        <li><img src="Imagenes/social-twitter.png" alt="Twitter"></li>
        <li><img src="Imagenes/socialfacebook.png" alt="Facebook"></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<!-- Cuerpo de la página -->
<section class="Container">
    <section class="Container">
        <div class="Contenido_Derecha">
            <h1 class="Conte_1">RESCATE</h1>
            <h3 class="Conte_1">ETAPA UNO</h3>
            <hr class="Conte">
            <br>
            <p class="Parrafo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam ultricies hendrerit quam, eget finibus metus gravida vitae.</p>
            <img src="Imagenes/rescate.jpg" alt="Perrito2" class="Perrito2">
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="Container">
        <div class="Contenido_Izquierda">
            <img src="Imagenes/crowfunding.jpg" alt="Alimento" class="Alimento">
            <div>
            <h1>CROWFUNDING</h1>
            <h3>FINANCIAMIENTO</h3>            
            <hr class="Conte">
            <br>
            <p class="Parrafo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam ultricies hendrerit quam, eget finibus metus gravida vitae.</p>
            <br>
            <input type="button" value="Boton" class="Boton">
        </div>
    </section>   
</section> 

<!-- Pie de Página  -->
<footer class="Foter">
    <h3 class="Ultimos">Desarrollo Web & Mobil</h3>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.Contenido_Derecha{
  text-align:right;
}

.Conte{
  float:right;
  width:65px;
}

.Contenido_Derecha h3{
color:grey;
}
.Perrito2{
  width:350px;
  height:250px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="Contenido_Derecha">
  <h1 class="Conte_1">RESCATE</h1>
  <h3 class="Conte_1">ETAPA UNO</h3>
   <hr class="Conte">
            <br>
            <p class="Parrafo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam ultricies hendrerit quam, eget finibus metus gravida vitae.</p>
            <img src="https://adiestramientocanino.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/displasia-en-perros.jpg" alt="Perrito2" class="Perrito2" />
 </div>
```

En el div padre (en este caso el que tiene clase `Contenido_Derecha` se le coloca la propiedad `text-align: right`, para que el `hr` se haga más pequeño de los lados se usa la propiedad de `width` y al igual si quieres cambiar el ancho y alto de la imagen debes modificar su `width` y `height`

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos, su ayuda me sirvió demasiado :D, no tengo mucho conocimiento dentro de la plataforma, no sé si existe algún tipo de puntuación, pero muchas gracias :)